# Colorscheme vim depending on Project

Tags: vim

I have a project that uses Ruby & Javascript and I am really comfortable with a particular colorscheme.

However I have another project in PHP + HTML, and I would like to use another colorscheme. What should I do?

I have my vim configuration in `~/.vimrc`

Thanks

Comment: Read [Keep your vimrc file clean](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_vimrc_file_clean). Essentially, you just put the command `colorscheme myrubytheme` on the file `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim`, the command `colorscheme myphptheme` on the file `~/.vim/ftplugin/php.vim`, etc. (You must create the directories if they don't exist.)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `ftplugin` feature. First create the relevant directory:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/ftplugin
```

And second, add the line

```
filetype plugin on
```

to your `.vimrc`.

---

Now you can add language specific options to a file called `<language-name>.vim` located in the directory `~/.vim/ftplugin`:

```
cat <<EOF > ~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim
colorscheme myRubyTheme
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
EOF
```

(This creates the file `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim` and adds to it the contents presented.)

To determine the name of the language (as Vim understands it), open a file with the necessary file type (say `MyLibrary.js`) and type `:set ft`. For a JavaScript file Vim should return `filetype=javascript`, so the ftplugin for JavaScript should be named `javascript.vim`.

For a more thorough exposition read [Keep your vimrc file clean](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_vimrc_file_clean) on Vim's wiki page.